# Unique random code for user content and how to avoid multiple user accessing same data in entity

Tags: ios, swift, uuid

Using swift 3 IOS10 and core data. I was trying to generate a unique code or ID for user content and I did not use UUID as it's too long I need short memorable one- I generated an alphanumeric code by doing this: created an entity to hold a start up numeric code say 1000, saved it to core data table and every time a new user comes in I read the code from the database, add some equation let us say addition to making sure it's unique, then add some random characters to it for more security. my question is how can I guarantee that if multiple users accesses this area at the same time they will not get the same code number read from the database. is there anything can block the DB record once any user reads it so prevent multiple users reading same data from the table at same sec?

Comment: Are you talking about a unique id across different users on different devices using your app?

Comment: yes each user will upload certain content I need every time he uploads certain content to get unique ID for it

Comment: So the ID is being generated on your server and not in the iOS app?

Comment: I generate the ID I read it from a databse table in datacore, then I add specific number to it to be unique and assign it to the user, what I am afraid of is if 2 or more user accessed the application at the same time and accessed the codes table at the same time is there a chance for both of them to fetch same code

Comment: sorry I think I didnot get your question wrong - excuse me what do you mean by the ID generated on my server? I am sorry I am new to IOS coding